How to modify JsonSerializerOptions WriteIndented behavior inside a Converter - System.Text.Json
open System
open System.Text.Json
open System.Text.Json.Serialization

type Point = { x: int; y: int }

JsonSerializer.Serialize ({ x=3; y=4 })

type JsonConverterPointNotIndented () =
    inherit System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<Point>()

    override _.Read (_, _, _) = raise <| NotImplementedException()

    override c.Write (writer, value, options) =

        let o = JsonSerializerOptions ()
        o.WriteIndented <- false // will be ignored, will write indented
        o.PropertyNamingPolicy <-JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseUpper // but this will be considered

        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, o)

let o = JsonSerializerOptions()
o.WriteIndented <- true
o.Converters.Add(JsonConverterPointNotIndented())
JsonSerializer.Serialize ({ x=3; y=4 }, o)

// output:
val it: string = "{
  "X": 3,
  "Y": 4
}"

// instead of
val it: string = "{"x":3,"y":4}"


parameter writer of type Utf8JsonWriter decides whether value will be written as indented or not. WriteIndented is a hint for JsonSerializer indicating whether to set this options when creating writer. You need to create new Utf8JsonWriter, serialize point to intermediate buffer, than copy it into original writer with WriteRawValue

Related or duplicate: In System.Text.Json is it possible to specify custom indentation rules?.

@dbc related but not a duplicate, i read that other post in detail yet it does not explain the very precise question here above, why the json options are ignored inside the converter.

As @JL0PD remarked, the JsonSerializerOptions() are just a hint, the writer has the actually used indent property, which is immutable. So one has to create a new reader, over a new buffer, like so:
type JsonConverterPoint () =
    inherit System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<Point>()

    override _.Read (_, _, _) = raise <| NotImplementedException()

    override c.Write (writer, value, options) =
        let ms = MemoryStream()
        let w = Utf8JsonWriter ms
        w.WriteStartArray()
        w.WriteNumberValue(value.x)
        w.WriteNumberValue(value.y)
        w.WriteEndArray()
        w.Flush()
        writer.WriteRawValue(ms.ToArray())

let o = JsonSerializerOptions()
o.WriteIndented <- true
o.Converters.Add(JsonConverterPoint())
JsonSerializer.Serialize ([|11;22|], o) // indented, normal array
JsonSerializer.Serialize ({x=12; y=34}, o) // not intented !! yeah: "[12,34]"

This is obviously not performant and using System.Text.Json from C# with Source Generators is quite certainly the way to go if performance matters.
Looks like the indent problem is nicely solved by this attribute:
[JsonSourceGenerationOptions(WriteIndented = true)]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/source-generation?pivots=dotnet-8-0
